# Wicket autocomplete with comboboxes and IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, wicket, wicket-6

I have form in which there is AutoCompleteTextField and two combo boxes (DropDowns in wicket).

When drop down for autocomplete is shown, combo boxes are hidden in IE6.

[image: hidden combo boxes in form with AutoCompleteTextField]

My test page code is:

```java
package net.betlista;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.wicket.Session;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.autocomplete.AutoCompleteTextField;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.DropDownChoice;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.TextField;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;

public class AutoCompleteAndDropDownTestPage extends WebPage {

    public AutoCompleteAndDropDownTestPage() {
        final DropDownChoice<Integer> drop1 = new DropDownChoice<Integer>("drop1", getNewList(15));
        drop1.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        final DropDownChoice<Integer> drop2 = new DropDownChoice<Integer>("drop2", getNewList(10));
        drop2.setOutputMarkupId(true);

        Session.get().setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        final AutoCompleteTextField<Integer> auto = new AutoCompleteTextField<Integer>("auto", new Model<Integer>(null)) {
            @Override
            protected Iterator<Integer> getChoices(final String input) {
                return getNewList(20).iterator();
            }
        };
        add(auto);

        add(drop1);
        add(drop2);
        add(new TextField<String>("text"));
    }

    private static List<Integer> getNewList(final int upTo) {
        final LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < upTo; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

test page markup is

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Insert title here</title>
        </head>
    <body>

        <form>
            <input type="text" wicket:id="auto"/><br>
            <select wicket:id="drop1"></select><br>
            <select wicket:id="drop2"></select><br>
            <input type="text" wicket:id="text"/><br>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Wicket does NOT support IE6, so I'm looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to upgrade to 6.7.0, this issue sees fixed : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4893

Comment: I just tested in 6.8.0 and it's fixed.